# What is the best way to embed an executable into my Visual Studio project?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, dll, exe

I have an executable with dll dependencies that I am using in my program and I want to be able package the other exe and dlls together with my application. This is a c# application and I am not sure what the other exe is (c# or c++).

As of now, I am just referencing an external file (C:\blah\bin\blah.exe) with the exe and dlls, but this won't work once other people start using the application and will need the exact exe file location.

Is there a good way for me to embed this exe into my application?

Comment: @paqogomez, I think then he'd need to save it to disk somewhere in order to run it.  (Sounds like he's using Process.Start.)  Better would be to make it a "Content" item in his project so that it gets copied by the installer.  (Do ClickOnce installers copy "Content" files?  I don't know for sure.)

Comment: You could also build an installer that deploys the dependancies to the same install location (or a known location, such as user app data).

Answer (score 0):

You can use resources for that purpose: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/319292/

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f45fce5x(v=vs.90).aspx

Another link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7k989cfy(v=vs.90).aspx